# How to retrieve a list of tasks and bugs from TFS in a batch file?

Tags: tfs, batch-file, task

I would like to access the work items in our TFS programmatically. Shouldn't there be an obvious command line tool to extract such information? Or a WebService I can just call? I already have checked into using Excel - this is neat, but I want more hardcore...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the TFS API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146(VS.80).aspx).  Access to the same code used by Microsoft to create the Visual Studio integration and their version control command line tool ([tf.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0(VS.80).aspx)).

You can also take a look at the power tools.  [tfpt.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs2008/bb980963.aspx) is the power tool command line and has many other advanced features.  That said - you can do pretty much what you want with the SDK.

The new version of the power tools will be out soon, and that looks to have [Powershell support](http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/archive/2008/10/01/preview-of-the-next-tfs-power-tools-release.aspx) coming

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

If you download [tfs power tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/tfs2008/bb980963(en-us).aspx) you can use "tfpt query" to your advantage.